# Excel VBA Print to PDF - with cell reference file name and folder path

Tags: excel, pdf-generation, vba6

I am trying the save/print excel report 30 pages to PDF.
file and folder path set to the cell reference.

I tried with the below code, Please help me to clear the issue at the end.

RUN TIME ERROR '1004'

Document not saved. an error may be encountered when saving

```
Sub PrintToPDF()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vDir As String
    Dim pdfName As String
    Dim fileSaveName As String
    Dim separator As String: separator = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim FSO As Object

    ' Set the worksheet to print (e.g., "REPORT" sheet)
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REPORT")

    ' Get the folder path from INPUT!B6
    vDir = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT").Range("B6").Value

    ' Get the file name from INPUT!B5
    pdfName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT").Range("B9").Value

    If vDir = "" Or pdfName = "" Then
        MsgBox "Folder path or file name is missing. Please provide both a folder path and a file name."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Check if the folder exists, and create it if it doesn't
    If Dir(vDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir vDir
    End If

    ' Check if the file name has a ".pdf" extension
    If Right(pdfName, 4) <> ".pdf" Then
        pdfName = pdfName & ".pdf"
    End If

    ' Build the full file path
    fileSaveName = vDir & separator & pdfName

    ' Create a FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Check if the file already exists
    If Not FSO.FileExists(fileSaveName) Then
        ' Set the print area for the "REPORT" sheet (e.g., A1:AK2107)
        ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:AK2107"

        ' Export the "REPORT" sheet as PDF and open it after publishing
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=fileSaveName, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        MsgBox "PDF File Saved in " & vDir

        ' Clear the print area setting
        ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Else
        MsgBox "This PDF file already exists in the same system folder. or May be Opened"
    End If

    ' Release the FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting Run time error - while saving the file.

Comment: stopped here -        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=fileSaveName, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Comment: RUN TIME ERROR '1004'

Document not saved. an error may be encountered when saving

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown when the pathname not exist on the computer. The method doesn't create non existing folders. First you have to create all the folders and after then can you save the file. The folders have to be created one after one.

```
fso.createfolder "C:\users\Username\where\folder1"
fso.createfolder "C:\users\Username\where\folder1\folder2"
```

and after it can save the file.

Update:

I check this code which then opens in the browser with the selected chart example on the sheet or if nothing selected the whole sheet with several pages.

```
Sub myccc()
filesavename = "C:\users\myname\desktop\mypdf.pdf"
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=filesavename, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

That is the code is OK.
Pls. try.

Comment: folder are clearly set ad path reference give to cell. If i manually add pdf with the same file name in the exact path. It will the alert saying that This PDF file already exists in the same system folder, which means my folder and file name is clearly set.

Comment: @humm I added a test to the answer.